# jQuery img slider not working

Tags: jquery, image

I am having a problem with a jquery img slider... I simply cannot get it to show up... any ideas on what i am doing wrong... I div myslideshow is put inside of a content div..

When i look in the sourcecode in firebug e.g. i can see that the markup is there and the pictures are being linked correctly - the slider just wont start..

Here is the HTML markup, Script for the plugin and the CSS

```
<div id="myslideshow">
                <ul class="bjqs">
                <li><img src="img/slidepic1.png" height="330" width="986" alt="slide1"/></li>
                <li><img src="img/slidepic2.png" height="330" width="986" alt="slide2"/></li>
                <li><img src="img/slidepic3.png" height="330" width="986" alt="slide3"/></li>
                <li><img src="img/slidepic4.png" height="330" width="986" alt="slide4"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

!-- Load jQuery og plug-in  til slider galleriet-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/basic-jquery-slider.js"></script>

     <!--  funktionen for selve animationen mm. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#myslideshow').bjqs({
          'width' : 970,
          'height' : 520,
      'animationDuration' : 1200,
    'showMarkers' : false,
    'centerControls' :true,
    'useCaptions' : false,
    'keyboardNav' : false,
    'showControls' : false,
        });

      });
    </script>



/* Basic jQuery Slider essential styles */

ul.bjqs{
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:none;
}
.bjqs-slide li{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}

ul.bjqs-controls li a{
  display:block;
  padding:5px 10px;
  position:absolute;
  background:#fff;
  color:#fd0100;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

a.bjqs-prev{
  left:0;
}

a.bjqs-next{
  right:0;
}

 p.bjqs-caption{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

 ol.bjqs-markers{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-50px;
}

 ol.bjqs-markers li{
  float:left;
  margin:0 3px;
}

 ol.bjqs-markers li a{
  display:block;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  border:4px solid #fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  background:#000;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow:0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

ol.bjqs-markers li.active-marker a{
  background:#fd0100;
}
```

Comment: 'showControls' : false, removed this extra , like this 'showControls' : false

Comment: can you share the link where have you tried this ?

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam is absolutely right, could you make a jsfiddle or [codepen](http://codepen.io/)?

Comment: Is `src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.1.js"` a valid path on your server? Can you execute any jquery command on the page from inside your `ready()` function? Try adding `alert("Hi!");`

Comment: here is the page: http://mmd3e12dae73.keaweb.dk/eksamen/home.php
and yeah, i the path is valid :-) 
At one point it (without me doing anything) showed the first picture of the slide - but didnt do anything - when i updated the page it went back to being black..

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is not able to detect any javascript on your page. But I see that there are references to your jquery and scripts.